# Can't rearrange vault because of Living Quarters/dweller limit

Tags: fallout-shelter

So first of all, I know one obvious solution to this problem is to allow enough dwellers to die so that I can destroy a living quarters, but since they're almost all maxxed out I'd rather not do that if I don't have to...

Basically I'm maxxed at 200 dwellers, and because of the tutorial, I had a living quarters room just to the right of my vault entrance. I wanted to stage this with 6 more "vault guards" to help kill off the deathclaws when they arrive. The problem is, unless I take the time to ensure either an all male or all female living quarters, they will get busy and make my female dwellers pregnant, limiting their ability to go out and scavenge. (I do this on a kind of a rotation.)

Basically I want to switch the living quarters I have there with a storage room, but I can't destroy the living quarters because I need it to support the 200 dwellers, and I can't add another living quarters elsewhere because I'm at the limit. Is there *any* solution that doesn't involve killing off a few dwellers? I'll do it if I have to, but I'd rather not if possible.

Sadly I also can't destroy just 1/3 of the living quarters at a time, meaning I'd only have to kill off 2 dwellers, but unlike building, destroying does the entire room, not just 1/3rd of it like when you build.

Comment: Just to clarify: the game would not allow you to construct or upgrade additional living rooms when you have reached the limit on the available dweller number whether you have filled the limit or have space in the vault?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "whether you have filled the limit"... The game will not allow me to construct new (or upgrade existing) living quarters because I have exactly enough to support 200 dwellers. If I had space in the vault to destroy an existing one, that would resolve the issue -- the question is about resolving the situation *without* murdering dwellers. :)

Comment: As for the concern with getting dwellers pregnant, why are you assigning dwellers to living quarters anyway? If you don't have anywhere to assign them to, build something - anything - to keep them busy so they aren't a drain on resources.  If it is so that you can "protect" those rooms, that's what a Mr Handy is for- he'll probably keep the bad things at bay until you assign nearby dwellers to take care of the problem.

Comment: @nailbones I had two living quarters next to my vault entrance to use as a gauntlet for raiders and deathclaws, since they will go the full level before descending further into the vault. The problem I was facing was that my male and female "guards" were intermingling on the job, so-to-speak, so I'd have vault guards who were heavily armed/armored, but the females would get pregnant so they would not fight or defend, they'd just run around screaming. I wanted to replace the living quarters with storage rooms so they didn't have beds to use. My Mr. Handy can't take 3 deathclaws himself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the game currently is, there is no way to manage this, without getting rid of your dwellers first.

The main issue is that the only way to allow yourself to remove/rebuild the living quarters is to reduce the population. This means either killing (sending them to scavenge until they die) or evicting them, and yes, you will have to do this for enough dwellers to reduce the total population by the amount that one Living Quarters holds - i.e. 40.

I am yet to test this, but it may be possible to reduce this problem in future, by splitting up your Living quarters into individual rooms (rather than combining them). This will mean more rooms in your vault in total, but the population control is far less severe the next time you wish to rebuild.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe the game supports this directly.

You may have some luck using a save editor, depending on the platform on which you play the game. I have in the past used [Fallout Shelter Save Editor](https://robot9706.github.io/FSSE/) with success to re-arrange my vault. I have used this on PC to edit a save from the Steam version of the game. It claims to work on Android as well.

There are other save editors reachable via google, but I have no experience to back up the claims they make about their capabilities.